# How do I draw a letter onto a table using its cells?

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I have a little project where I have to draw the letters of the alphabet onto a table using its cells. The way letter is drawn is by the user being asked what letter they would like to enter. When the user enters a letter, it will appear on the table by colouring the cells of the table.

The table is 5 x 5 and is created using an array. This is the array:

```
$Grid = array( array(1, 2, 3,4,5),
           array(6, 7 , 8, 9,10),
           array(11, 12 , 13, 14, 15),
           array(16, 17 , 18, 19, 20),
           array(21, 22 , 23, 24, 25)
         );
```

So for instance if the user enters "I", cells '8',13''18' will be coloured in. 
The problem is i'm not too sure how to connect my table and letters with user input as well as colour in the cells.

Here is the php containing my full code:

```
<?php

$table = '';
$letter = $_POST['letter'];


$Grid = array( array(1, 2, 3,4,5),
               array(6, 7 , 8, 9,10),
               array(11, 12 , 13, 14, 15),
               array(16, 17 , 18, 19, 20),
               array(21, 22 , 23, 24, 25)
             ); 

$letters = array
 (
        array ("A" => $Grid[0][2], $Grid[1][1], $Grid[1][3], $Grid[2][1], $Grid[3][1], $Grid[2][2], $Grid[2][3], $Grid[3][3]),
        array ("B"),
        array ("C"),
        array ("D"),
        array ("E"),
        array ("F"),
        array ("G"),
        array ("H"),
        array ("I" => $Grid[1][2], $Grid[2][2], $Grid[3][2]),
        array ("J"),
        array ("K"),
        array ("L"),
        array ("M"),
        array ("N"),
        array ("O"),
        array ("P"),
        array ("Q"),
        array ("R"),
        array ("S"),
        array ("T"),
        array ("U"),
        array ("V"),
        array ("W"),
        array ("X"),
        array ("Y"),
        array ("Z")

    );

//print_r($letters);
//var_dump($letters);


/*if($letter == i)
{
//$table .='<td bgcolor = "#0000CC">;'.$letters['I'].'</td>';
echo '<td bgcolor = "#0000CC">'.$letters['I'].'</td>';
}*/



$table .= "</table>";
?>

<?php if (count($Grid) > 0): ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/LGrid.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
                <table>
                        <tbody>
                                <?php foreach ($Grid as $row): array_map('htmlentities', $row); ?>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <tbody>
                </table>
                <br>

                <form action="" method="POST">
                <table border="0" width="200"  >
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Enter Letter:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="letter"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="Submit" value="Place letter"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table >    
                </form>
        </body>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

CSS:

```
table,  td  {
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

 td     {
            padding: 5px;

        }
```

Any help on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't need to over complicate the map with the indexes of the table, you can work them out simply by providing the values.  Or if you want to be more creative, create a `Point` class, and treat them as co-ordinates.

Comment: Sorry could you explain further details what you meant please? I'm still fairly new to php.

Answer (score -1):

You're kind of close, and I can see that the route you're trying to go down would work eventually, but it's created alot more work for yourself than you need. I wouldn't even store coords for the table cells, there's no need, as they're going to be the same every time anyway.

I'd roughly go about it like this, commented throughout to explain my logic. Mapped capital I as an example for you.

```
$chosen_letter = 'I'; // This letter should correspond to one that we've defined
$mapped_letters = [
    'I' => [
        2 => [1,5], // 2nd column on rows 1 & 5
        3 => [1,2,3,4,5], // 3rd column on rows 1,2,3,4,5
        4 => [1,5] // 4th column on rows 1 & 5
    ],
];

// Start building our table
$html = '<table border="1">';
for ($row = 1; $row < 6; $row++) { // creating 5 rows
    $html .= '<tr>';
    for ($col = 1; $col < 6; $col++) { // each of those rows has 5 columns
        $background_color = ''; // By default, the created cell will not have a background colour

        if (isset($mapped_letters[$chosen_letter][$col]) // But if the mapped letter exists
            && in_array($row, $mapped_letters[$chosen_letter][$col])) { // AND the current row is listed as one of the mappings
            $background_color = 'background-color:#000;'; // change this cell colour to black
        }
        $html .= '<td style="width: 50px;height:50px;' . $background_color . '"></td>'; // output cell
    }
    $html .= '<tr>';
}
$html .= '</table>';

echo $html; // output table
```

This would then output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your way helped a lot and was a lot more simpler and easier to understand. I always have a habit of overcomplicating things. So once again thank you very much.